# Few questions about kohonen neural network

Tags: neural-network

I have big data set (time-series, about 50 parameters/values). I want to use Kohonen network to group similar data rows. I've read some about Kohonen neural networks, i understand idea of Kohonen network, but:

1. I don't know how to implement Kohonen with so many dimensions. I found example on CodeProject, but only with 2 or 3 dimensional input vector. When i have 50 parameters - shall i create 50 weights in my neurons?
2. I don't know how to update weights of winning neuron (how to calculate new weights?).

My english is not perfect and I don't understand everything I read about Kohonen network, especially descriptions of variables in formulas, thats why im asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes, you'll need 50 inputs for each neuron
2. you basically do a linear interpolation between the neurons and the target (input) neuron, and use `W(s + 1) = W(s) + Θ() * α(s) * (Input(t) - W(s))` with Θ being your neighbourhood function.

and you should update all your neurons, not only the winner

which function you use as a neighbourhood function depends on your actual problem.
a common property of such a function is that it has a value 1 when i=k and falls off with the distance euclidian distance. additionally it shrinks with time (in order to localize clusters).

simple neighbourhood functions include linear interpolation (up to a "maximum distance") or a gaussian function

Answer (score 3):

One should distinguish the dimensionality of the map, which is usually low (e.g. 2 in the common case of a rectangular grid) and the dimensionality of the reference vectors which can be arbitrarily high without problems.

Look at http://www.psychology.mcmaster.ca/4i03/demos/competitive-demo.html for a nice example with 49-dimensional input vectors (7x7 pixel images). The Kohonen map in this case has the form of a one-dimensional ring of 8 units.

See also http://www.demogng.de for a java simulator for various Kohonen-like networks including ring-shaped ones like the one at McMasters. The reference vectors, however, are all 2-dimensional, but only for easier display. They could have arbitrary high dimensions without any change in the algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you would need 50 neurons. However, these types of networks are usually low dimensional as described in this [self-organizing map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohonen_network) article. I have never seen them use more than a few inputs.
2. You have to use an update formula. From the same article: `Wv(s + 1) = Wv(s) + Θ(u, v, s) α(s)(D(t) - Wv(s))`

Comment: How to calculate `Θ(u, v, s)`? I can't find any formula on Wikipedia.